# why can't i get Dropbox to not start on system startup?

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

On both Ubuntu and Kubuntu i have a problem with Dropbox, the "start Dropbox on system startup" setting is unchecked by default, but Dropbox still starts when i start the machine.

Comment: Is it by chance being launched by "Startup Applications"? This might be overriding any settings you chose in Dropbox settings.

Comment: i don't know... i'll have a look, where do i find settings for startup applications

Comment: Typically it would be in the Dash under startup applications. You may find this useful. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup